# how to align a table in HTML in qt

Tags: html, qt

I am trying to create a table that can be printed in an HTML format file, and it's printing but the only concern is that it's printing to the left of the file and I want it at the centre of the file. What code should be added to make it print at the centre of the page?

Below is the code which I have used to print the table:

```
 css1 = "<style type="text/css">";
css1 += "table.tbl {border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: 
    black;margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;color: black;}";
css1 += "table.tbl td {padding: 3px;}";
css1 += "table.tbl th {padding: 3px;font-size: 18px;}";
 css1+="</style>";

     text1 = "<table width=\"50%\"  cellspacing=\"0\" class=\"tbl\">";
     text1 +=("<tr><td>"+qfont+"</td><td>" + name) +"</td>");
     text1 +=("<tr><td>"+qTestedBy+"</td><td>" +TestedBy+"</td>");
     text1 +=("<tr><td>"+qCurrentDate+"</td><td>" + 
   QDate::currentDate().toString() +"</td>");
     text1 +=("<tr><td>"+qCurrentTime+"</td><td>" + 
 QTime::currentTime().toString() +"</td>");
 QFile qHtmlFile(qFileName);
if (qHtmlFile.exists())
{
  if(qHtmlFile.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite))
  {
 QTextStream qData(&qHtmlFile);
  qRep = qIndex+qAll+css+text
qTextRep.document()->setHtml(qRep);
  qTextRep.setFont(qFon);
    qData << qTextRep.document()->toHtml();

          qDebug("Report Created");

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Align table to the center when you creating a table

```
text1 = "<table width=\"50%\"  cellspacing=\"0\" class=\"tbl\" align=\"center\">";
```

or try add `margin: auto;`  instead of `margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px`

in your css

Comment: [align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table#attr-align) attribute is deprecated